# Google Drive File Stream on OS X fails to ls files

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

I am running Google Drive File Stream Version: 25.252.289.1612 on OS X 10.12.6 which mounts/Volumes/GoogleDrive/

Open a Bash shell (I use iTerm3). When I *ls* (or *ls -a*) this directory, I get no results.  But if I use tab completion, I can see the two subdirectories, 'My Drive' and 'Team Drive' as well as some other stuff.  As I *cd* into subdirectories, again ls shows no files but tab completion shows them.  And I can operate on files/directories.  So if there is a file *foo.gsheets* , I can open * open foo.gsheets* which will launch in Chrome, for example.  Or if I had *foo.txt* I could *vi foo.txt*. I checked that I had read/write/execute permission on files and dirs.  And even tried to *sudo ls* .

Any ideas?  Here is my mount
   drivefs on /Volumes/GoogleDrive (dfsfuse_DFS, local, nodev, nosuid, synchronous, mounted by aberezin)

Maybe related to the implemenation of osxfuse
  [https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/503](http://%20Running%20Google%20Drive%20File%20Stream%20Version:%2025.252.289.1612%20on%20OS%20X%2010.12.6%20which%20mounts/Volumes/GoogleDrive/When%20I%20ls%20(or%20ls%20-a)%20this%20directory,%20I%20get%20no%20results.%20%20But%20if%20I%20use%20tab%20completion,%20I%20can%20see%20some%20the%20two%20subdirectories,%20'My%20Drive'%20and%20'Team%20Drive'%20as%20well%20as%20some%20other%20stuff.%20%20As%20I%20cd%20into%20subdirectories,%20again%20ls%20shows%20no%20files%20but%20tab%20completion%20shows%20them.%20%20And%20I%20can%20operate%20on%20files/directories.%20%20So%20if%20there%20is%20a%20file%20foo.gsheets%20,%20I%20can%20open%20which%20will%20launch%20in%20Chrome,%20for%20example.%20%20Or%20if%20I%20had%20foo.txt%20I%20could%20vi%20it.%20I%20checked%20that%20I%20had%20read/write/execute%20permission%20on%20files%20and%20dirs.%20%20And%20even%20tried%20to%20sudo%20ls%20.%20Any%20ideas?Here%20is%20my%20mountdrivefs%20on%20/Volumes/GoogleDrive%20(dfsfuse_DFS,%20local,%20nodev,%20nosuid,%20synchronous,%20mounted%20by%20aberezin)Maybe%20related%20to%20this?https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/503)

Comment: Have a similar issue on osx 10.11.6.  Did you solve the problem eventually?

Comment: Same problem for me.

Comment: No, it doesnt have the priority for me to dig into osxfuse.

Comment: Which version of `ls` are you using (is it `/bin/ls` or do you use a newer, non-default version)? I have the same problem with iterm 2 when I use a newer version of `ls` that I install with homebrew, but `/bin/ls -al` works. I've also given iterm full disk access through the Security & Privacy settings in System Preferences.

Comment: $which ls #I installed gnutls @3.5.19_0 via macport but Ill try /bin/ls 
/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/ls

Comment: Thank you @HAL9001  It is indeed true that /opt/local/libexec/gnubin/ls (installed my macports from gnuutils) cannot see files but /bin/ls can.

Comment: I'd recommend updating the original question with this information. Also, since my post `/bin/ls` will fail for me in a terminal that has been open for a "long time".

Comment: I was having the same issue on Ubuntu via (WSL): https://stackoverflow.com/q/49944731/635160

Comment: I'm able to `ls` with iterm2 on the latest MacOS

Answer (score 0):

First remove the cache using this command:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/DriveFS/
```

Then ls into the directory.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot repro the problem ATM but will try this when I do hit the problem again.